# Split string using underscore as marker

Tags: vb.net, string, split, filenames

Its been a while since Ive split strings however i need to split and rearange text ussing "_" underscores as markers where to split the string.

eg:

```
TOM_here_was
```

would then become

```
here_was_TOM
```

how do I do that in VB.net?

Comment: I would first split the string using the '=' as delimiter then make a new string in a different order.

Comment: What is the rule for the ordering?

Comment: @ Tim qua the rule of ordering, I have a file name with a client number then the number that follows is a starting date and the last number is an end date. eg 1111_20140201_20140228. tom was here probably not a good example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the rule for the ordering?

According to the split, use [`Split("_"c)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an array:

```
Dim tokens = "TOM_here_was".Split("_"c)
```

Now you have all parts, if you want a random order for example (since it's not clear):

```
tokens = tokens.OrderBy(Function(s) Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray()
```

**Update** acc. your comment:

> I have a file name with a client number then the number that follows
>   is a starting date and the last number is an end date. eg
>   1111_20140201_20140228. tom was here probably not a good example

```
Dim path = "C:\Temp\1111_20140201_20140228.txt"
Dim fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
Dim tokens = fileName.Split("_"c)
If tokens.Length = 3 Then
    Dim client = tokens(0)
    Dim startDate, endDate As Date
    Dim parsableStart = Date.TryParseExact(tokens(1),
                                      "yyyyMMdd",
                                      Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                                      startDate)
    Dim parsableEnd = Date.TryParseExact(tokens(2),
                                      "yyyyMMdd",
                                      Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                                      endDate)
    If parsableStart AndAlso parsableEnd Then
        Console.WriteLine("Client: {0} Start: {1} End: {2}", client, startDate, endDate)
    End If
End If
```

If you want to order the files in a directory you could use LINQ:

```
Dim startDate, endDate As Date
Dim fileNames = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Temp\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
Dim orderedFilenames =
    From path In fileNames
    Let fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
    Let tokens = fileName.Split("_"c)
    Where tokens.Length = 3
    Let client = tokens(0)
    Let startDateParsable = Date.TryParseExact(tokens(1), "yyyyMMdd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, startDate)
    Let endDateparsable = Date.TryParseExact(tokens(2), "yyyyMMdd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, endDate)
    Where startDateParsable AndAlso endDateparsable
    Order By startDate, endDate
    Select New With { fileName, client, startDate, endDate }

For Each fn In orderedFilenames
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} Client: {1} Start: {2} End: {3}", fn.fileName, fn.client, fn.startDate, fn.endDate)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myString = "TOM_here_was"
Dim splitArray() As String

splitArray = Split(myString, "_", -1)
```

In this example, splitArray() would have the following values:

- splitArray[0] = TOM
- splitArray[1] = here
- splitArray[2] = was

After that, you can use the splitArray to create a new string however you want.

Since you haven't specified how you're re-organizing the new string, I can't really help other than to do something like:

```
Dim newString = splitArray[0] & "_" & splitArray[2] & "_" & splitArray[1]
```

to get: TOM_was_here

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

I will tell you the most easiest way. Here is how I would do it. First we will take it as a string `test` and we will use `test.Split()` and specify splitting from underscore.  And then store the split parts in the variable `parts`.

We will join them together in `Label1` (You can do it in variable or whatever you want).

## Code And Example

```
Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
             Dim test As String = "TOM_Here_was"
             Dim parts As String() = test.Split("_"c)
             If parts.Length >= 3 Then
                  Label1.Text = parts(1) & "_" & parts(2) & "_" & parts(0)
             End If

        End Sub
End Class
```

I hope it would work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a generic usage function for your problem:

```
''' <summary>
''' Splits an String and rotates an amount of splitted tokens.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="String">Indicates the string to split and rotate.</param>
''' <param name="Delimiter">Indicates the delimiter to split.</param>
''' <param name="Rotation">Indicates the rotation count.</param>
''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
''' <exception cref="Exception">Rotation index out of range.</exception>
Private Function SplitAndRotate(ByVal [String] As String,
                                ByVal Delimiter As Char,
                                ByVal Rotation As Integer) As String

    Dim Parts As String() = [String].Split(Delimiter)

    If Rotation >= Parts.Length Then
        Throw New Exception("Rotation index out of range.")
    End If

    Return String.Format("{0}{1}",
                         String.Join(Delimiter,
                                     From s As String In Parts Skip Rotation) & CStr(Delimiter),
                         String.Join(Delimiter,
                                     From s As String In Parts Take Rotation))

End Function
```

Usage:

```
    Dim str As String = SplitAndRotate("TOM_here_was", "_"c, 1)
    ' Result: here_was_TOM
```